# register nib in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

Im new to programming and swift and working through iOS 13 for beginners. I have followed all steps and can't figure out out how to get past this issue. The app won't finish launching in simulator and is stuck on the launch screen. **"could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier header - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"** error is in app delegate and I can't figure out where I would register a nib. The error is on the class declaration line.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

}
```

I feel like the error is something in this code connecting to the delegate.

```
import UIKit

class ExploreViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath)
        return headerView
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "exploreCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindLocationCancel(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
        
    }

}
```